# Why does supertest keeps showing jest.setTimeout(2000), but even if I tried changing the timeout it still shows timeout?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, supertest

I have tried everything there is to it but supertest keeps showing to set timeout to more than 2000ms and I have set it to 100000ms, but still it never works.

I have tried the async method, changing timeout, and alot methods.

I have attached my code below

if you need the whole code let me know i will share it.

I am using jest --watchAll for running the file

PS: thanks in advance

```
const request = require("supertest");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const app = require("../app");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const User = require("../models/user");
dotenv.config({ path: "../config.env" });
let conn;
const apiBaseUrl = "/api/v1";

beforeAll(async (done) => {
  const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/api-test";

  conn = await mongoose.connect(url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  });
  await User.create({
    role: "admin",
    firstName: "New",
    lastName: "Admin",
    email: "admin@someone.com",
    password: "helloworld123",
    airline: "air",
    airlineId: "12345",
    airlinePassword: "123",
  });
  await User.insertMany(require("./files/usersMockData.json"));
});

afterAll(async (done) => {
  conn.connection.db.dropDatabase();
});

describe("User Module", (done) => {
  let token;
  let adminToken;
  let randomUser;
  // Normal User Functions
  it("POST -> Create User", (done) => {
    // Invalid Email
    return request(app)
      .post(`${apiBaseUrl}/users`)
      .send({
        email: "name@name",
        password: "123",
        airline: "SomeAirline",
        airlineId: "12345",
        airlinePassword: "123",
      })
      .expect(400, done);
  });
  // Invalid password less than 8 letter
  it("POST -> Create User", (done) => {
    return request(app)
      .post(`${apiBaseUrl}/users`)
      .send({
        email: "name@gmail.com",
        password: "123",
        airline: "SomeAirline",
        airlineId: "12345",
        airlinePassword: "123",
      })
      .expect(400, doe);
  });
  // Invalid airline name from enum
  it("POST -> Create User", (done) => {
    return request(app)
      .post(`${apiBaseUrl}/users`)
      .send({
        email: "name@gmail.com",
        password: "somepass123",
        airline: "SomeAirline",
        airlineId: "12345",
        airlinePassword: "123",
      })
      .expect(400, done);
  });
  // Working
  it("POST -> Create User", (done) => {
    return request(app)
      .post(`${apiBaseUrl}/users`)
      .send({
        email: "airline@gmail.com",
        password: "somepass123",
        airline: "someair",
        airlineId: "16957",
        airlinePassword: "123",
      })
      .expect(201)
      .then((res) => {
        expect(res.body).toEqual(
          expect.objectContaining({
            status: expect.stringContaining("success"),
            data: expect.objectContaining({
              _id: expect.any(String),
              email: expect.any(String),
              airline: expect.any(String),
              airlineId: expect.any(String),
            }),
          })
        );
      });
  });
});
```